# Display ReportViewer (ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials) in a separate, dragable window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have an SSRS report displaying fine in my .aspx page, except that it needs to display in its own window. Now, I can form a url to the report server and open it easily like this, but it is not what I need to do in this case.

```
   string url = "http://testserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?  %2fSQLReports%2fTestReport&rc:Parameters=Collapsed&ID=" + ID.ToString() + "";
   string script = "window.open('" + url + "','')";               
   if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("NewWindow"))
   {
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "NewWindow", script, true);
   }
```

What I need to do is from code-behind, open the way we are now forming the reportview on the aspx page having it's parameters passed along with it:

```
    (ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials)
```

I have researched this for quite some time and cannot seem to find a definitive answer to a solution for this. I've tried the following:

1. `ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender` (there is a way to make this
   draggable but this breaks in IE10 due to a known bug). Patch is not
   an option because these are on end-user client machines.
2. JavaScript popup
3. `Server.Redirect` or `Transfer` to a separate page, passing the parameter values along in session variables.

This is a report spanning several pages so on postback you will need to not reload the report.

Comment: Don't all answer at once LOL